# Cannot get WSDL in JBoss 7. Same code works in Jboss 6

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jboss7.x

I am porting a WS application from Jboss6/Java 6 to Jboss7/Java7 combination. When I query for the WSDL from the browser, I get exceptions (see below from the Jboss console log) in Jboss 7 (using 7.1.1.Final version) but the query works perfectly in Jboss 6.

```
10:28:59,175 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--0.0.0.0-9991-3) 10:28:59,175 INFO  [e.Filter]: BSLProcessLog|ajp--0.0.0.0-9991-3|doFilter|Environment is = uat|
10:28:59,178 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myservice].[MYService]] (ajp--0.0.0.0-9991-3) Servlet.service() for servlet OasService threw exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot obtain destination for: //myservice/service/oas
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.findDestination(RequestHandlerImpl.java:164)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:81)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:113) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
        at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.3.GA.jar:2.0.3.GA]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at com.vzw.etm.ws.filter.WsdlAccessFilter.doFilter(WsdlAccessFilter.java:48) [classes:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:397) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:505) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:445) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
```

The CXF versions are different, but when should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Here is my web services module.

Comment: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
    <wsdl-host>jbossws.undefined.host</wsdl-host>
    <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
    <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
         <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_ MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
          </pre-handler-chain>
   </endpoint-config>
</subsystem>

Comment: I see the followig in the logs:16:44:22,751 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.metadata.MetadataBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-4) Add Service
 id=OasService
 **address=https://jbossws.undefined.host:8443/myservice/service/oas**
 implementor=my.example.ws.oas.OasService
 invoker=org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker
 serviceName={http://oas.ws.example.com/}OasServiceService
 portName={http://oas.ws.etm.vzw.com/}OasServicePort
 wsdlLocation=null
 mtomEnabled=false

Comment: the address needs to be myserver.com:port/myservices/service/oas